# Include additional Packages

Tags: xetex, packages, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

How to include additional packages like for glossary, font, etc… in LaTeX?

I am using XeLaTeX.

How to install additional packages and how to include them (after we got installed) in you document?

Comment: Please be a little more specific. Are you talking about how to install additional packages or how to include them (after they got installed) in you document? In the first case please tell use which TeX distribution under which OS you are using. Thank you.

Comment: how to install additional packages and how to include them (after they got installed) in you document?

Comment: Could you tell us with TeX distribution (e.g. MikTeX, TeXLive, ...) and which operation system (e.g. Windows 7, Some Linux, Mac OS, ..) you are using. Also note that you don't need to tag questions here with 'latex' and that the 'latex-project' tag is really just about the project to develop LaTeX and not about how it use it.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/215) are likely useful.

Comment: Given the answer you have given to your own post, it looks like this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/215 and I don't think your answer here is the best or safest way to add new packages. So I think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am wondering if what you are looking for is `\usepackage`? If you read any LaTeX tutorial, you will find it.

Comment: Yes Correct. how to install additional packages and how to include them (after they got installed) in you document?

Comment: Depends on your tex distribution (TeXLive, MikTex, ...). Most packages you will ever need are already in those distributions. Read its docs to find out.