# How do I set the search path for MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, paths

Simple question: I have a folder I'd like to add to my MikTex search path (containing a stack of include and `.sty` files.)

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to add a folder to the search path.

(For the record, I'm on Windows 7, and using TeXWorks to generate pdf files via XeLaTex, all installed via MikTex 2.8 )

Comment: Not a duplicate of this? [Include additional Packages - closed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24051/include-additional-packages)

Comment: That questions is more about "what is the search path now"; I'm more interested in "how do I change the search path", that is, I don't want to use any of the default locations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open "Maintenance" or "Maintenance (Admin)" in Start Menu, select "Settings". You will open "MiKTeX Options" window. (a.k.a MiKTeX Console for Windows)

[image]

You can add a root path of your own. e.g. `X:\localtexmf\`

Then you can put your own LaTeX styles into `X:\localtexmf\tex\latex\WHATEVER`. `tex\latex` is predefined position in [TDS](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf), you can't use arbitrary directory structure.

Then run "Refresh FNDB" command in "General" tab in "MiKTeX Options" window.

Comment: "Maintenance"? I have Windows 7, but don't understand what you are talking about.