# How to Install an Unavailable Document Class for LyX on Windows

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I am writing a paper that needs to be formatted using the LNCS style, which is not available out of the box with LyX 2.2.3. How do I install it on my LyX install for Windows 10 x64?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. It's a hybrid of [this online how-to](http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/index.php?title=How_to_install_Springer_LNCS_Style_for_Lyx) and [my older question on how to do this on Mac OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84918/4024)

**Step 0**: Quit LyX

**Step 1**:

> Download llncs2e.zip, which contains llncs.cls and llncsdoc.sty. I just googled for a download link and got mine from [here](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)

**Step 2**:

> Copy those files to the folder ... \ MiKTeX 2.7 \ tex \ latex \ lncs, where ... \ MiKTeX 2.7 is the folder in which MiKTeX is installed. On some systems, copy to ... \ MiKTeX 2.7 \ texmf \ latex \ lncs. The lncs folder will probably need to be created.

Mine was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`, where I had to create the `lncs` folder (which requires admin privilege escalation). I extracted `llncs.cls` and `llncsdoc.sty` to this folder.

**Step 3**:

> Run "texhash" from the command line.

Open up `cmd` and run `texhash`. Very straightforward

**Step 4**:

> Run MikTex Settings. Press "Refresh FNDB" under General. Then, possibly, "Update Formats".

It wasn't obvious to me where MikTeX Settings was. [This other SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30089/4024) showed me what to do. Just look for `admin` in the Start Menu's search bar and you'll see `MikTeX Settings (Admin)`

**Step 5**:

> Open Lyx and select Tools -> Reconfigure

Very straighforward

**Step 6**:
You're done. Go do a happy dance or something

Comment: I had the same problem and I basically followed steps 1 to 6 proposed by inspectorG4dget above (thanks) but had to improvise because my installation doesn't make use of MiKTex but it is using TeXLive. Then, I just had to skip step 4 and everything is working so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MikTex 2.9 on Windows10 and I didn't get the MikTex Settings by searching for it in the start menu. Instead I found it in the MikTex Console - run as admin, go to "Tasks" on the menu bar and run "refresh file name database". Took me some time to realize FNDB stood for "file name database"...

The previous answer is a very good answer, and I still got stuck on step 4 - if I skipped step 4 the document class just wouldn't become available. I would like to put it here in case someone else stumbles across it. Sorry for not being able to add a comment, I don't have enough reputation here.

Comment: Your answer is valid as much has changed since the other answer was written Today you are correct Step 1) Find and Open MiKTeX-console  2) Navigate to Packages  Find/Filter e.g. LLNCS in packages 3) Install using + 4) Use TASKS Refresh Filename Database 5) repeat the above as admin if you did the above as user