# Class LNCS in LyX doesn't work

Tags: lyx, miktex, lyx-layouts, miktex2.9

I have the same problem as posted here: 
[How to Install an Unavailable Document Class for LyX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405117/how-to-install-an-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-windows)

I want to install the unavailable class LNCS in Lyx 2.2.2. I've tried those steps in the link but it still doesn't work. The Latex error message

> File 'llncs.cls' not found

appears in Lyx when I run a template that uses LNCS class.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you refresh the F.N.D.B.?

Comment: `Alt+H C` (Menu Help > Customization), but I  would use a true LaTeX editor.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, actually yes i've already refreshed FNDB and followed all the required steps in the link.

Comment: @HafidiYousra: AS I don't have LyX, I can give only general advice.  I think you might try to compile  your  code  from a standard editor like TeXmaker of TeX studio, and see if it works. You'll have a detailed .log file.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, i've found the solution and everything work well now. this question is answered.

Comment: Fine! Note that apckages which are not part of the distribution should nbe preferably installed in a `local root`, say `TeXMFlocal`, to be declared via `MiKTeX Settings`, `root` tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem,

A little clarification for those who want to install a class in LyX. Please follow these steps that are mentioned in the previous link:

**Step 0:**

Quit LyX

**Step 1:**

Download `llncs2e.zip`, which contains `llncs.cls` and `llncsdoc.sty`. I just googled for a download link and got mine from here.

**Step 2:**

Copy those files to the folder `...\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\lncs`, where `...\MiKTeX 2.7` is the folder in which MiKTeX is installed. On some systems, copy to `... \MiKTeX 2.7\texmf\latex\lncs`. The `lncs` folder will probably need to be created.

Mine was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`, where I had to create the `lncs` folder (which requires admin privilege escalation). I extracted `llncs.cls` and `llncsdoc.sty` to this folder.

**Step 3:**

Run

```
texhash
```

from the command line.

**Step 4:**

Run MiKTeX Settings. Press "Refresh FNDB" under General. Then, possibly, "Update Formats".

**Step 5:**

Open LyX and select Tools -> Reconfigure

Very straightforward

---

**But be sure to put the `llncs.cls` and `llncsdoc.style` files in:**

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\lncs
```

PS. Create the folder `lncs` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TexLive, put the llncs.cls in the following path:

`TEXLIVE_ROOT_PATH/YEAR/texmf-dist/tex/latex/llncs2e`

The YEAR is 2018 if you are using TexLive 2018.

Run `texhash`.

Open Lyx and 'Tools' -> 'Reconfigure'.

Now in 'Document' -> 'Settings' -> 'Document Class', you should be able to see `Lecture Notes in Comp. Science (LNCS)` in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened for me when I downloaded the Springer LaTeX template and tried importing the `tex` file into `Lyx`. I got this error: "The selected document class Lecture Notes in Comp. Science (LNCS) requires external files that are not available. The document class cannot be compiled until the following prerequisites are installed: llncs.cls. See section 3.1.2.2 (Class Availability) of the User's Guide for more information."

[image]

So I looked opened the "Help" menu of the Lyx editor to view the User guide and did some searching to find [this](https://kawahara.ca/springer-lncs-latex-template/), [this](http://www.fpl.uni-kl.de/conferences/Hangzhou-07/Hangzhou-Keynote-2007/grid.hust.edu.cn/ica3pp07/authorinfo.htm), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407608/class-lncs-in-lyx-doesnt-work), [this](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/index.php/How_to_install_Springer_LNCS_Style_for_Lyx&prev=search), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx), but nothing worked.

**The solution:**
I finally noticed that on opening one guy's tex file, the error didn't show up. Comparing the difference, I found the reason.

Springer's default tex file has this line:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
```

It should actually be this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
```

And that's it. The error didn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I placed the files `llncs.cls` and `splncs04.bst` in the same folder as my .lyx file, the document would compile and display correctly with LyX's pdflatex option.

These files can be obtained from [the instructions for authors page provided by Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) in the [LaTeX2e Proceedings Templates (zip)](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)

```
LyX Version 2.3.5.2
(Thursday, June 25, 2020)

Library directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Resources\
User directory: ~\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3\
Qt Version (run-time): 5.12.5
Qt Version (compile-time): 5.12.5
```